# Label in table environment not appearing

Tags: tables, labels, placeins

I tried to change the position of the label, nevertheless it didn't work.
Here follows the code:

```
\noindent
blahblah \ref{tab:1}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c|c } 
     \hline
     A & 0 \\ \hline
     B & 1   \\ \hline
     C & 2   \\ \hline
     D & 3  \\ \hline
     E & 4   \\ \hline
     F & 5 \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{blahblah} 
    \label{tab:1}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "change the position of the label". Are you maybe referring to the table's caption?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document (WME: Minimal Working Example), which we can compile as it id and which  reproduce your problem.